# Where do i put template that i want to render

Tags: python, django, django-piston

The following is the code that i got from a website for basic-authentication using "django-piston".
Here i have login.html page which i wana show,where do i put that and what is this realm keyword in the following code.................

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from piston.resource import Resource
from piston.authentication import HttpBasicAuthentication
from mysite.myapp.api.handlers import BlogpostHandler
auth = HttpBasicAuthentication(realm="Django Piston Example")
blogpost_handler = Resource(BlogpostHandler, authentication=auth)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^blogpost/(?P<post_slug>[^/]+)/', blogpost_handler),
   url(r'^blogposts/', blogpost_handler),
)
```

Comment: Does "Django Piston Example" show up somewhere when you try to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Django searches for template directories in a number of places, depending on your template-[loader settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#loader-types), but the most basic way of specifying template directories is by using the [TEMPLATE_DIRS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#the-template-dirs-setting).

Look in your django-piston app where the templates are. Eg:

```
/path/to/site-packgages/django-piston/templates/template.html
```

If you have the default loader settings applied in your project, than you can override the templates by creating at template with the same path and filename but then in your project directory:

```
/path/to/projectdir/django-piston/templates/template.html
```

A realm is a community or territory over which a sovereign rules; a kingdom. 2. A field, sphere, or province: the realm of science.

Reading the Piston source code I think a realm is just a name that is passed to the authentication handler and probably only used by that handler to inform the user about the area he is about to receive access to: "Your about to receive access to [realm]".

Disclaimer: The realm guess is my best guess. I'm not a Piston user.